# PHP Form to send data to localhost database not working

Tags: php, database, forms, localhost

I'm writing a program that, 1. gives a form containing, "UserID", and "Message". The code for that is here:

```
<form display:inline-block; text align: left; id="form1" name="form1" action="notificationinsert.php" method="post">  <p>
    <label><u><b>Enter your notifications here:</b></u> The system will automatically use the date and time (EST) of your entry. If this is a general notification, enter 99 for userid.</label><br><br>
       </p>
        <p>
        <label for="userid">Userid:</label>
        <input type="text" name="userid" id="userid">
        </p>
         <br></br>
         <p>
         <textarea name="notification" id="notification" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea>
         </p> 

               <p>
               <p>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
    
    <p>&nbsp; </p>
</form>
```

Then, 2. sends that to another php file, notificationinsert.php (as shown in the code above). notificationinsert.php would send the data to my database as well as email it to the user with that userid. I have pasted that too:

```
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";


// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require '/home/bitnami/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require '/home/bitnami/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require '/home/bitnami/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';



    date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
    //$tdate = date("r");
    $tdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    
    // Attempt insert query execution
    // Create prepared statement
    $sql = "INSERT INTO notifications (userid, date, notification) VALUES (:userid, :date, :notification)";  
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    
    // Bind parameters to statement
    $stmt->bindParam(':userid', $_REQUEST["userid"]);
    $stmt->bindParam(':date', $tdate);
    $stmt->bindParam(':notification', $_REQUEST['notification']);
    
    // Execute the prepared statement
    
    $stmt->execute();
    

    $sql = "SELECT emailaddress FROM userprofile WHERE userid = :userid";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    
    // Bind parameters to statement
    $stmt->bindParam(':userid', $_REQUEST["userid"]);
    // Execute the prepared statement
    $stmt->execute();

    $results = $stmt->fetch();
    $emailaddress = $results["emailaddress"];
    $notification = $_REQUEST['notification'];
        
        // Send email to user with the token in a link they can click on
    // Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
        $mail->Host       = 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com';   // Set the SMTP server to send through
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username   = 'AKIAVH6N4Z2KTX7UPGEX';                     // SMTP username
        $mail->Password   = 'BIOJHb/5Hu68Cj5KpH6oxvS572ftDATnT8p67D+PRO+D';     // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
        $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above
    //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('e@gmail.com', 'E');
        $mail->addAddress($emailaddress);           // Add a recipient
        $mail->addReplyTo('e@gmail.com', 'E');
                
        // Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Notification from E';
        $mail->Body    = $notification;
        $mail->send();
        
    header("location: welcome.php");

    
    // Close connection
    unset($pdo);
```

Finally, 3. a new page (notification.php) fetches the data and expresses it in a table:

```
<div>      
 
          
    <p><h3><center>My Notifications</center></h3></p>
</div>     
<br>
<br>
<center><table style='border: solid 2px black; padding: 8px' width="100%"; >
<col width = "20%"> 
<col width = "80%"> 
<tr>

<th style='padding-top: 10px; 
  padding-bottom: 10px; text-align:center;  background-color: #2DA81F;
  color: white'>DATE</th>
<th style="padding-top: 10px; 
  padding-bottom: 10px; text-align:center; background-color: #2DA81F; 
  color: white">Notification</th>

</tr>

</center>
 

<?php

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 
    function __construct($it) { 
        parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
    }

    function current() {
        return "<td style='width:250px;border:1px solid black; text-align:left' height='25px'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
    }

    function beginChildren() { 
        echo "<tr>"; 
    } 

    function endChildren() { 
        echo "</tr>" . "\n";
    } 
} 


// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT date, notification FROM notifications WHERE userid = :userid1 or userid = :userid2"); 
    $userid2 = "99";
    // Bind parameters to statement
    $stmt->bindParam(':userid1', $_SESSION["userid"]);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userid2', $userid2);
    $stmt->execute();

    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
        echo $v;
    }


$pdo = null;
?>

</table>
</div>
```

However, when i submit the form, it gives me an error:
Warning: require(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myfolder/home/bitnami/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myhestia/notificationinsert.php on line 20

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myfolder/home/bitnami/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.21/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myfolder/notificationinsert.php on line 20

Comment: Page is giving a server error? Is status code 500?

Comment: `display:inline-block; text align: left;` is invalid in a `form` element. Missing quotes and `style` attribute.

Comment: @user3783243 yea, im getting status code 500

Comment: Enable error reporting and check your logs.

Comment: @Kids-teach-kids can you add the below code lines on top of the first page and report the errors and warnings displayed?
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: alright i edited the code with what i got from that